# Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver error when running Heroku Rake Task

Tags: heroku, watir

I have the following rake task that I am trying to run on Heroku:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'watir'

desc "where the good stuff happens"
task :get_interesting_data => :environment do

    browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, headless: true
    ...some web scraping and other tasks...
end
```

I am getting the error

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.`

...when I run the rake task. It looks like there was previously a buildpack at `https://github.com/ivandeex/heroku-buildpack-firefox.git` that is no longer available. Any ideas on how to make this run?

Comment: Have you found a solution yourself? I installed the buildpacks, but still its the same error

Comment: No. Never did find a solution.

Comment: I have started a bounty, lets see if someone take a serious look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Use these heroku buildpacks:
http://github.com/buitron/firefox-buildpack
and http://github.com/buitron/geckodriver-buildpack

Also, set path as per their wiki and make sure you add `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=ENV['FIREFOX_BIN']` in the code.